# Django INNER JOIN with GROUP BY queryset

Tags: python, sql, django, django-models

How can I get the following SQL queryset in Django?

```
SELECT abbreviation, COUNT(tat_value) FROM t_tat 
INNER JOIN t_tests ON t_tat.test_id = t_tests.test
GROUP BY test
```

These are my class models:

```
class tat(models.Model):
    test = models.ForeignKey(tests)
    tat_value
    ...

class tests(models.Model):
    test = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, default=0)
    ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [django annotation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-for-each-item-in-a-queryset) features will do this:

```
from django.db.models import Count
tests.objects.annotate(Count('tat'))
```

Optionally, use `values_list` to select down to just the abbreviation and count, if that's important.